# VB6 form cuts off toolbar at run-time on Windows 7/8/10 but not XP

Tags: forms, vb6, toolbar

[image: Image depicts the toolbar truncated on the right by the host form's right edge.]

I have a Visual Basic 6.0 application which has several forms hosting toolbars. One of these forms, as depicted in the image, displays with its toolbar cut off or truncated on the right by the form's right hand edge. There should be a 'Paste' button also displayed.

At design time the form displays correctly. At run time it also displays correctly on Windows XP, but not on 7/8/10. I am using a VMWare VM running XP Professional 32-bit for development. Notable properties include: form is re-sizeable; toolbar does not wrap. I have tried setting the form width manually in the 'Load' event with no effect. Aside from this issue I've had no problems running this Visual Basic 6.0 application on any version of windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hard to tell, but this might be a High DPI issue.

Comment: Does it change anything if you run your exe in [a compatibility mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible) on Windows 7/8/10?

Comment: And if you were to maximize the form, or manually resize it to make it wider, can tell us what happens?  It looks me me like you either need smaller toolbar graphics or smaller toolbar buttons.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics.  In W7, W8 and W10, there is an extra entry: PaddedBorderWidth  Normally set to -60.  What happens if you set it to 0?

Comment: Having a PaddedBorderWidth of -60 gives an extra thick border of 4 pixels.  If you consider the border on both sides, 8 pixels, may be enough to push your icon to half width, since most VB6 icons are appx 16-24 pixels wide but try it an see if that is the root cause.

Comment: Thanks guys I'm sorry for the late response I've been in hospital a while. What it cam down to was getting the width set right at design time, just trial and error. I extended the forms right edge across well past the tool bar and it still truncates (reason unknown) but not to the extent where the tool bar is cut off. Many thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Why you use Windows XP as environment of development?
You should use always the latest version of Windows (Windows 10) to avoid this problems.
You should never use Windows XP as a development environment because it is too different from Windows versions (Vista and later). It would make sense only if you use the **Classic** theme in all versions of Windows, otherwise you will find many differences because system object measurements vary from theme to theme. Only the Classic theme is constants on all Windows versions.

My solution example: on my applications I use save/load routines to manage the form size and position (I use a simply user INI file). So, when the user change them will be saved on INI file, the next session the same size e position will be loaded again.

However, this solve the problem with *resizable* form, for *fixed* forms don't.

Finally, i suggest you to create a Windows 10 (VMWare or VirtualBox), install all VB6 environment, and use this to develop.
But, of course, if your host system is already Windowx 10, then use this directly.